# Delete from the second occurrence of pattern block

Tags: linux, sed

Every line beginning with "  File:" and "Modify:"
I need to delete from the 2nd occurrence of "Modify" pattern in blocks of "Modify" lines.
Keeping the first occurrence of "Modify" in every "Modify block"

Based on this text

```
  File: /Music/David Bowe/1.mp3
Modify: 2010-11-24 09:36:33.000000000 -0200
Modify: 2016-04-13 11:32:58.692458900 -0300
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Tom.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:15.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Hero.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-26 07:21:56.000000000 -0200
Modify: 2017-04-13 11:32:58.282458400 -0300
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/AbsoluteBeginners.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:07.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/ImAfraidOfAmericans.mp3
Modify: 2011-11-13 08:54:57.000000000 -0200
Modify: 2015-04-13 11:32:58.732459000 -0300
Modify: 2016-04-13 11:32:58.692458900 -0300
Modify: 2016-01-01 21:18:53.348891500 -0200
```

I want get this result

```
  File: /Music/David Bowe/1.mp3
Modify: 2010-11-24 09:36:33.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Tom.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:15.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Hero.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-26 07:21:56.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/AbsoluteBeginners.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:07.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/ImAfraidOfAmericans.mp3
Modify: 2011-11-13 08:54:57.000000000 -0200
```

`sed '/^Modify:/d' sample.txt` doesn't work because I delete all occorrences of the pattern.

`sed '/^Modify:/2,$d' sample.txt`
trying to delete from the 2nd to the last occurrence doesn't work again (syntax error)

Comment: sed '/^Modify:/d' sample.txt   -  doesn't work because I delete all occorrences of the pattern.

Comment: sed '/^Modify:/2,$d' sample.txt - trying to delete from the 2nd to the last occurrence doesn't work  (syntax error)

Comment: I'd just do `perl -ne 'print if /^  File:/ .. /^Modify:/'`. Doing it with sed is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/File/,/Modify/p' file
```

Turn off seds normal print-every-line and only print when specified. Print the range of lines between `File` and `Modify`, all other lines will not be printed.

A more robust solution:

```
sed -n '/^  File:/{N;/^Modify:/M!D;p}' file
```

Use the `-n` grep-like option. Match specific `File:` line, append the next line and match the specific `Modify:` line and if no match delete the first line and repeat, otherwise print both lines and repeat.

N.B. When the first line is deleted, seds normal processing is not followed. Because the pattern space is not empty, no next line is automatically read and cycle of commands begins as if it has been read already i.e. the second line that was appended with the `N` command, now becomes the first line in the pattern space and the first instruction to be executed is `/^  File:/`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Great job!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/File:/N; /File:/p'  file
```

or shorter:

```
sed -n '/File:/{N;p}' file
```

Output:

```
  File: /Music/David Bowe/1.mp3
Modify: 2010-11-24 09:36:33.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Tom.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:15.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Hero.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-26 07:21:56.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/AbsoluteBeginners.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:07.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/ImAfraidOfAmericans.mp3
Modify: 2011-11-13 08:54:57.000000000 -0200
```

From `man sed`:

Option:

> `-n`: suppress automatic printing of pattern space

Commands:

> `N`: append the next line of input into the pattern space
>
> `p`: print the current pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep:

```
$ cat > trash.txt
  File: /Music/David Bowe/1.mp3
Modify: 2010-11-24 09:36:33.000000000 -0200
Modify: 2016-04-13 11:32:58.692458900 -0300
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Tom.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:15.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Hero.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-26 07:21:56.000000000 -0200
Modify: 2017-04-13 11:32:58.282458400 -0300
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/AbsoluteBeginners.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:07.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/ImAfraidOfAmericans.mp3
Modify: 2011-11-13 08:54:57.000000000 -0200
Modify: 2015-04-13 11:32:58.732459000 -0300
Modify: 2016-04-13 11:32:58.692458900 -0300
Modify: 2016-01-01 21:18:53.348891500 -0200
^D

$ grep File -A 1 trash.txt | grep -v -- --
  File: /Music/David Bowe/1.mp3
Modify: 2010-11-24 09:36:33.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Tom.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:15.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/Hero.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-26 07:21:56.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/AbsoluteBeginners.mp3
Modify: 2010-10-22 11:12:07.000000000 -0200
  File: /Music/Music/David Bowe/ImAfraidOfAmericans.mp3
Modify: 2011-11-13 08:54:57.000000000 -0200
```

Explanation:

- `-A 1` means 1 line of context after the match (lines with File:)
- `| grep -v -- --` this one is to remove lines with `--` (the -A flag places a `--` line in order to mark group separators) so we need this second grep: `-v` means "match only lines without this pattern" and we the first `--` is just escaping the second `--` because `--` has a special meaning on most gnu command line utilities